# Android Studio spinner problem with ArrayListof kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, spinner

//Model

```
Class DeviceBT
class DeviceBT(
    private val id: Long,
    private val name: String,
    private val macAddress: String
)
```

//MainActivity :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

//Spinner Test
    var listDeviceBT = arrayListOf<DeviceBT>()
    listDeviceBT.add(BTDeviceModel(1,"Peripherique 1", "00:00:00:00:01" ))
    listDeviceBT.add(BTDeviceModel(2,"Peripherique 2", "00:00:00:00:02" ))
    listDeviceBT.add(BTDeviceModel(3,"Peripherique 3", "00:00:00:00:03" ))
    listDeviceBT.add(BTDeviceModel(4,"Peripherique 4", "00:00:00:00:04" ))

//spinner adapter
    val spinnerBTAdapter = ArrayAdapter<DeviceBTDataLight>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,listDeviceBTLight)
    spinnerBTAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    spinner_BTAssocied.adapter = spinnerBTAdapter
}
```

the list of spinner don t return text, return Adapter.BTDeviceModel@456654e
how to get the value of name ?
Thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override toString method in DeviceBT class.

```
override fun toString(): String {
        return name
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but don't works, name is unknow.
But if add    val name: String = name     it's work in function toString